# WEB API | How to implement delete

Tags: javascript, php, rest

I'm building a web app which utilizes a custom built API to add, remove and read items.

I currently use a very simple PHP-based API.
My code looks something like this

JS

```
function deleteProject(ID) {
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //something wiht rsponse
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/api.php?deleteProject=true&ID="+encodeURIComponent(ID), true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip, x-gzip, identity");
  xhttp.send();
}
```

PHP

```
session_start();
//login & auth check
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true || $_SESSION['userLVL'] < 2) {
  header("location: /login");
  die('Not Logged In');
    }
//deleteProject
if (isset($_GET['deleteProject']) && $_GET['deleteProject'] == 'true') {
  //script with code to delete project from database
  require('../php/delete.php');
}
```

Recently I watched a talk by a senior back-end developer where she started out by showing a few of her projects.

She then said something along the lines of "And yes, I also made this mistake" following a slide what showed an API structure of the DELETE function where it looked like this:

`/API/DELETE/ID`

Which is quite similar to my structure. When I tried dive deeper I couldn't find any resources that pointed out what the best way to structure an API was.

All I could find were ASP/C# tutorials about HTTP methods.

I would really appreciate some help in this field.

Comment: Ah, so it wasn't about the structure, rather it was about the HTTP method. Why is it a bad way to change data?

Comment: @Joeri because https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4 defines which method to use when: GET for retrieval, POST for processings.

Comment: you should use the correct HTTP methods, eg a request sent with a delete to the resource '.../products/1' will delete the product with id 1. a get request to the same URL will get that product. Patch or Put will update the product. it makes your routing a lot simpler

Comment: @nathan, don't worry. I do use authentication...

Comment: @AmigoJack , thank you. I found a few new request types of which I didn't know they existed...